# Show subtitles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing an application in which I have a window with a `MediaElement`. The user can play the movie in this window. I would like to add an option to play the movie with subtitles. I know how to display text over the `MediaElement` but the problem is, how to display subtitles at certain intervals.

My solution (which doesn't work): I will parse a `.src` file to a dictionary where `Key` is `start time` and `value` is `text`.

Next, I have a timer with a 1 ms interval and at each interval I would check if the movie-time exists in the dictionary. If yes, I will show the value. Problem is, that I'm not able to check dictionary every millisecond but the interval is about 20 ms and this is the problem. So do you know how to call it every 1 millisecond?

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string text = MediaElement.Position.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
   Thread t = new Thread(() => SearchThread(text));
   t.Start();
   if (MediaElement.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
      timer.Text = String.Format("{0} / {1}", MediaElement.Position,
                   MediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.ToString());
}

private void SearchThread(string pos)
{
   string text = srcFileControler.Get(pos); //take value from dictionary if exist
   if (text != "")
      this.txtSub.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
           new Action(() => { txtSub.Text = text; }));  
}
```

Comment: This sounds horribly inefficient. At the least, you could 'normalise' the times as you parse them - basically round them to the nearest 500ms. Then your problem becomes much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a more *reusable* approach that let's you seek, skip and replay. Since a lot of your code is missing in the question I've made a couple of assumptions of what it might look like.

Keep your subtitles in a simple class that contains at least a timestamp at which it should appear and the text to display. If at any time you want to display no text at all, simply add an entry with `String.Empty` for the Text.

```
public class SubtitleEntry
{
    public TimeSpan TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

To keep track of which position (timestamp and subtitle-index) you are, check if the next entry's timestamp is earlier than the last known timestamp. If the "current" subtitle entry has changed, raise an event to update the text.

```
public class SubtitleManager
{
    public event EventHandler<string> UpdateSubtitles; 

    private List<SubtitleEntry> _entries;

    private int _currentIndex = -1;
    private TimeSpan _currentTimeStamp = TimeSpan.MinValue;

    public SubtitleManager()
    {
        _entries = new List<SubtitleEntry>();
    }

    public void SetEntries(IEnumerable<SubtitleEntry> entries)
    {
        // Set entries and reset previous "last" entry
        _entries = new List<SubtitleEntry>(entries);
        _currentTimeStamp = TimeSpan.MinValue;
        _currentIndex = -1;
    }

    public void UpdateTime(TimeSpan timestamp)
    {
        // If there are no entries, there is nothing to do
        if (_entries == null || _entries.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Remember position of last displayed subtitle entry
        int previousIndex = _currentIndex;

        // User must have skipped backwards, re-find "current" entry
        if (timestamp < _currentTimeStamp)
            _currentIndex = FindPreviousEntry(timestamp);

        // Remember current timestamp
        _currentTimeStamp = timestamp;

        // First entry not hit yet
        if (_currentIndex < 0 && timestamp < _entries[0].TimeStamp)
            return;

        // Try to find a later entry than the current to be displayed
        while (_currentIndex + 1 < _entries.Count && _entries[_currentIndex + 1].TimeStamp < timestamp)
        {
            _currentIndex++;
        }

        // Has the current entry changed? Notify!
        if(_currentIndex >= 0 && _currentIndex < _entries.Count && _currentIndex != previousIndex)
            OnUpdateSubtitles(_entries[_currentIndex].Text);
    }

    private int FindPreviousEntry(TimeSpan timestamp)
    {
        // Look for the last entry that is "earlier" than the specified timestamp
        for (int i = _entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (_entries[i].TimeStamp < timestamp)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    protected virtual void OnUpdateSubtitles(string e)
    {
        UpdateSubtitles?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

In your window, that would look something like this:

```
private DispatcherTimer _timer;
private SubtitleManager _manager;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _manager = new SubtitleManager();
    _manager.SetEntries(new List<SubtitleEntry>()
    {
        new SubtitleEntry{Text = "1s", TimeStamp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)},
        new SubtitleEntry{Text = "2s", TimeStamp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)},
        new SubtitleEntry{Text = "4s", TimeStamp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)},
        new SubtitleEntry{Text = "10s", TimeStamp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)},
        new SubtitleEntry{Text = "12s", TimeStamp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12)},
    });
    _manager.UpdateSubtitles += ManagerOnUpdateSubtitles;
}

private void ManagerOnUpdateSubtitles(object sender, string text)
{
    txtSubtitle.Text = text;
}

private void BtnLoadVideo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) != true) return;

    element.Source = new Uri(dialog.FileName, UriKind.Absolute);

    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,50); //50 ms is fast enough
    _timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _manager.UpdateTime(element.Position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with an approach similar to Evk's solution but slightly different.

From an ordered list of subtitle (by time of appearance):

1. Take the first subtitle
2. Compute the remaining timespan before its moment of showing
3. Wait for that duration
4. Finally display it

Take the next subtitle, and repeat.

Here is a code using .NET async/await and Task.

```
public class Subtitle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the absolute (in the movie timespan) moment where the subtitle must be displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan Moment { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the text of the subtitle.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class SubtitleManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a task that display the specified subtitles at the right moment, considering the movie playing start date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="movieStartDate"></param>
    /// <param name="subtitles"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task ProgramSubtitles(DateTime movieStartDate, IEnumerable<Subtitle> subtitles)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            foreach (var subtitle in subtitles.OrderBy(s => s.Moment))
            {
                // Computes for each subtitle the time to sleep from the current DateTime.Now to avoid shifting due to the duration of the subtitle display for example
                var sleep = DateTime.Now - (movieStartDate + subtitle.Moment);

                // Waits for the right moment to display the subtitle
                await Task.Delay(sleep);

                // Show the subtitle
                this.ShowText(subtitle.Text);
            }
        });
    }

    private void ShowText(string text)
    {
        // Do your stuff here
        // Since the calling thread is not the UI thread, you will probably need to call the text display in the dispatcher thread
    }
}
```

You could add some other stuff like:

- If the moment is past, do nothing and take the next subtitle
- You could use a shared Timespan variable to manually shift all the subtitle moment of apparition (if the subtitles are not synchronized with the movie)
- Do not run the Task in the `ProgramSubtitles` function but let the caller run the function in a Task? (Depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's better to take another approach. When movie starts - grab first subtitle interval from the list (say it's 00:01:00) and start timer which will fire after this time. Then when this timer fires all you need is just show corresponding subtitle and repeat by grabbing next interval time and starting timer again. Some sketch code:

```
// assuming queue is "sorted" by interval
private readonly Queue<Tuple<TimeSpan, string>> _subtitles = new Queue<Tuple<TimeSpan, string>>();
// call this once, when your movie starts playing
private void CreateTimer() {
    var next = _subtitles.Dequeue();
    if (next == null) {
        ShowText(null);
        return;
    }
    System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => {
        timer.Dispose();
        ShowText(next.Item2);                
        CreateTimer();
    }, null, next.Item1, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}

private void ShowText(string text) {
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // show text
    });
}
```

Comment: My first thought was to suggest something like that. But then, one question came to my mind. Is the `Timer` object sufficiently accurate? I mean, If you set the `awake` to 1.254ms, does will be actually awake in 1.254ms or a little before or after, due to system/thread synchronization or stuff like that?

Comment: @fharreau it's not accurate to 1 ms, but is accurate enough I believe for given task (show subtitles). If you show subtitle ~10ms before or after actual time - should be good enough. But if not and you need very high precision (up to 1ms) - another solution is needed.